# Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I downloaded the GCM project from git and i was able to start the server (app engine for java) and also compile the client apk on the device. On startup the device successfully registers with the server and I can see the registration id when i go to

```
http://myserverip:8080/_ah/admin/.
```

The problem is when i hit the 'Send Message' button there is a message 'Single message queued for registration id ' and it doesn't do anything. 
[image]

Below is a screenshot of the error i noticed on the terminal. Am i missing something. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
[image: Below is the Screenshot of the error i noticed on the terminal].

[image]

Comment: It's not registering to your server, it's registering with GCM. Is your server registered with GCM?

Comment: @Prem how would i check that?

Comment: Once your client is registered with GCM, you pass that registration ID to your server, and you use that to send push messages.

Comment: @prem i tried the website given by 'eran' below and i received the notification on my device so it is definatel registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the screenshot - You are getting a 401 (unauthorized) status code - you are missing the API Key. 
Look in the code you downloaded for the place (it will probably be some string whose current value is something like "ENTER_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE") in which you should enter your API Key which belongs to the API Project whose ID you are using at the Client app as sender ID when you register to GCM.

Comment: Hi. There are two spots to enter the API key. One is ApiKeyInitializer.java and the other is the api.key file and i've entered my API key in both the places. And i've verified that it is the correct key.

Comment: @atar You can test your API key by trying to send a GCM message to your app from [this site](http://helmibaraja.com/gcm_demo.html) which features a simple server for sending GCM messages.

Comment: thanks for the link. I tested it and received the message on my device. So there must be something going on with my sender class.